# Is removing "thanks" a tiny, trivial edit that is discouraged?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have accessed the edit queue recently. Some edits there only remove "thanks" "thanks in advance" or correct minor spelling/grammar errors.

I think that these kinds of edits qualify as "tiny trivial" edits as, IMHO, they do not make questions more clear nor are helpful in any way.

Is it fine to reject this kind of edit?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's fine to reject edits like this.

While removing "Thanks" is generally beneficial, there's probably more that could be done to improve the post so these things should be addressed as well.

Of course, if the post is perfect apart from the "Thanks" then feel free to approve the edit.

Comment: @Rubén: Note, also, that there is [specific guidance in the help](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) not to use "signature, taglines, or greetings" in posts. I don't know if I'd consider such edits "trivial", but if that's the only change and they leave other problems in the post, I would certainly use the "Reject and Edit" option.